# Appium - Unable to create a new remote session

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am still trying to learn how to automate my testing processes. i got stuck here.
I' ve checked the system variables configurations which seemed ok.

JDK 13.0.2
Maven 7.3.0
Android 9
Java 8

i am trying to install an application to an android device. i could not find what am i missing?

**Error on appium**

```
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Android"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk","appium:deviceName":"Android","platformName":"android"}]}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1580218300028 (16:31:40 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time))
[Appium] 
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium]   DEPRECATION WARNING:
[Appium] 
[Appium]   The 'automationName' capability was not provided in the desired 
[Appium]   capabilities for this Android session
[Appium] 
[Appium]   Setting 'automationName=UiAutomator2' by default and using the 
[Appium]   UiAutomator2 Driver
[Appium] 
[Appium]   The next major version of Appium (2.x) will **require** the 
[Appium]   'automationName' capability to be set for all sessions on all 
[Appium]   platforms
[Appium] 
[Appium]   In previous versions (Appium <= 1.13.x), the default was 
[Appium]   'automationName=UiAutomator1'
[Appium] 
[Appium]   If you wish to use that automation instead of UiAutomator2, please 
[Appium]   add 'automationName=UiAutomator1' to your desired capabilities
[Appium] 
[Appium]   For more information about drivers, please visit 
[Appium]   http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/ and explore the 
[Appium]   'Drivers' menu
[Appium] 
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium] 
[Appium] Appium v1.15.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.37.2) session
[BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Android"
[BaseDriver]   },
[BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[BaseDriver]     {}
[BaseDriver]   ]
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 93dcbefd-6c27-48cf-aa6d-f6c7d48351aa
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\demirhan\Desktop\KazandiRioTestauto\Kazandirio\KazandirioTest\app\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     C:/Users/demirhan/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.0
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"a54eca38","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: a54eca38
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[ADB] Setting device id to a54eca38
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 28
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 9
[ADB] Device API level: 28
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy 1'
[AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Using the alternative activity name detection method because of: Could not find 'apkanalyzer.bat' in ["C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\bin\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\29.0.0\\apkanalyzer.bat"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'?
[ADB] Using 'aapt.exe' from 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\aapt.exe'
[ADB] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb.exe: error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''
[UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s a54eca38 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy'
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1580218302808 (16:31:42 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.pepsico.kazandirio.uat' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060065 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:186)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:125)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
[W3C]   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
[W3C]   at io.appium.apktools.AndroidManifestActivityHelper.decodeManifestXML(AndroidManifestActivityHelper.java:26)
[W3C]   at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:33)
[W3C] 
[W3C]     at ADB.packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest (C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\android-manifest.js:136:9)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 2825 ms - 4106
[HTTP]
```

**Error on Eclipse**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.pepsico.kazandirio.uat' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060065 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:186)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:125)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
    at io.appium.apktools.AndroidManifestActivityHelper.decodeManifestXML(AndroidManifestActivityHelper.java:26)
    at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:33)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TR-ADN-404G4H2', ip: '10.152.6.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.pepsico.kazandirio.uat' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060065 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:186)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:125)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
    at io.appium.apktools.AndroidManifestActivityHelper.decodeManifestXML(AndroidManifestActivityHelper.java:26)
    at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:33)

    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TR-ADN-404G4H2', ip: '10.152.6.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at testcases.Kazandirio.main(Kazandirio.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.pepsico.kazandirio.uat' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060065 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:186)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:125)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
    at io.appium.apktools.AndroidManifestActivityHelper.decodeManifestXML(AndroidManifestActivityHelper.java:26)
    at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:33)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TR-ADN-404G4H2', ip: '10.152.6.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\PepsiPromoConsumer.apk C:\\Users\\demirhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.pepsico.kazandirio.uat' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060065 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:186)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:125)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
    at io.appium.apktools.AndroidManifestActivityHelper.decodeManifestXML(AndroidManifestActivityHelper.java:26)
    at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:33)

    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\demirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 19 more
```

**pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>kazandirio.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>KazandirioTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
 <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.3.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

CODE

```
package testcases;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Kazandirio {
public static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    File app = new File ("C:\\Users\\demirhan\\Desktop\\KazandiRioTestauto\\Kazandirio\\KazandirioTest\\app\\app.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());


driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show your code that throwing this error?

Comment: i've added the code. thanks

Comment: You have to add platform name and platform version too. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985169/how-to-make-selectable-apppackage-and-appactivity-beforescenario-in-android-appi/59992189?noredirect=1#comment106112217_59992189