# how to Make selectable appPackage and appActivity BeforeScenario in android Appium Test Automation

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, appium-android, getgauge

I want to choose starting app(appPackage,appActivity) in @BeforeScenario to develop a test scenarios for multiple apps in one test project. I know use the start activity but because of security permission denial, I can not use it. The only working method is using capabilities in beforeScenario. Before start the test I want to choose the starting app.My Code:

`@BeforeScenario
    public void beforeScenario() throws MalformedURLException {

```
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities
            .setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "device");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "L2N4C19924005752");
    if (localAndroid) {
        logger.info("Local Browser");


        desiredCapabilities
                .setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,
                        notapadAppPackageName);
        desiredCapabilities
                .setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                        notepadAppActivityName);

    }

    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", false);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 30);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", false);
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    appiumDriver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);

    selector = SelectorFactory
            .createElementHelper(localAndroid ? SelectorType.ANDROID : SelectorType.IOS);
    appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    appiumFluentWait = new FluentWait(appiumDriver);
    appiumFluentWait.withTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

`

Comment: It will read itself from apk file. You have to pass different apk file to create session for multiple app

Comment: Ok Iwil Publish it again on above it start from @BeforeScenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass app name from VM aguements and base on that you can set driver instance. Please have a look on code below:

```
@BeforeScenario public void beforeScenario(String appName) throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    switch (appName) {
  case "notepadApp":
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,notapadAppPackageName);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,notepadAppActivityName);
    break;
  case "App-A":
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,appAAppPackageName);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,appApadAppActivityName);
    break;
    case "App-B":
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,appBAppPackageName);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,appBApadAppActivityName);
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("No matching app is found.");
}

    // Common desired capabilities set
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "device");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "L2N4C19924005752");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", false);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 30);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", false);
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    appiumDriver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);

    selector = SelectorFactory
            .createElementHelper(localAndroid ? SelectorType.ANDROID : SelectorType.IOS);
    appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    appiumFluentWait = new FluentWait(appiumDriver);
    appiumFluentWait.withTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Comment: In my project I dont use apk file. Just develop test cases according to different apps. Ex. my project has different specs for each apps. So I want to make a parameter that when start the test, the driver know that which apps to run the test.

Comment: So you don’t need to install app on device before you run test cases? Do have all app’s data (appPackage and appActivity).

Comment: Yeap, I have the appPAckage and appActivityname. Just needed setup the beforetest class to choose which app start the test

Comment: You can decide it with the help of VM arguent. Use switch case for multiple app and pass appName to decide which app you want to launch

Comment: I will do it. Please share your code in question that way you are creating driver instance. I will modify same code.

Comment: @SilasHayri  Pleasw check it and let me know

Comment: I do it but when run the mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs -Dtags="BrowserTest3" -DappName="notepadApp" I got the `Gauge Specs execution failed. null: GaugeExecutionFailedException `

Comment: please give me the mvn gauge:execute example and also how to run it on intellij @muzzamil

Comment: Any idea or solution??

Comment: May i know where are you getting exception (line)? Gauge is maven architecture type?

Comment: when try to run lin intellij I got the ` Failed: Before Scenario
Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments   `

Comment: Yeap, you can run the gauge in maven by mvn gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs -Dtags="BrowserTest3" -DappName="notepadApp" . May I give the beforescenario parameters in the wrong place or code

Comment: do you have added **"appName"** in Pom.xml so you can use as VM arguements

Comment: How to add it into pom.xml

Comment: here you can check. it comes in maven sure fire plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750348/how-to-add-vm-args-using-pom-xml-plugin

Comment: @SilasHayri are you ab;e to fix it ?

Comment: let me check it and give the result asap

Comment: `<properties>
        
            <jvm.appName>Browser</jvm.appName>

    </properties>

                        <arg>${jvm.appName}</arg>
      
                    <argLine>${jvm.appName}</argLine>` here is added my pom and still get the same error

Comment: I think we should use json file in config

Comment: Better if you can try app name as hardcoded in **beforeScenario** to get to know where is error. I hope your were able to launch app before

Comment: Actually, I just want to run my test scenario acording to each app by it's name. Ex. When run the browser test, the appPAckage and appActivity change acording to browser and so far others.But I just got the error

Comment: Yes you can try with multiple app in each execution by passing multiple. I am just stuck with gauge. I have no hands on with gauge.

Comment: So how do you choose the apps package and activityname in junit appium

Comment: Same way I have mentioned but I don’t know why you are able to access it through pom.xml and another thing if you can pass all this information as hardcoded still you are getting exception. If your code was working fine before it should work now as I am we are just deciding app pakg and activity using appname

Comment: do you have another solution like dynamic capabilies for beforeclass?